# Webstorm sidebar all files are gone on sidebar

Tags: webstorm

[image: Screenshot]

Webstorm - all files are gone on sidebar

The files do exist.
Do you know what's going on?

Comment: 1) What version is that? 2) Have you tried `File | Invalidate caches...` and restart IDE? Any difference? 3) You can always delete project settings (`.idea` subfolder) while project is closed in IDE and re-configure project from scratch (just use `Open Directory` for that)

Comment: I tried invalidate caches and all the problem is solved
Thank you LazyOne

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Webstorm ver 10

I tried invalidate caches and all the problem is solved

Now i can see all the files

Thank you so much LazyOne